# Convert JKS to PEM in one step

Tags: openssl, keytool, pem, jks

Converting truststore client.jks, in JKS format, to client.pem in PEM format...
I know how to do this in two steps, with an intermediate (.p12) file:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.jks -destkeystore client.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12
$ openssl pkcs12 -nodes -in client.p12 -out client.pem
```

But it seems like there should be a way to pipe the output in such a way as to avoid saving to disk the intermediate (client.p12) file.  Something like:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nodes -out client.pem -in < keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.jks  -deststoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /dev/stdout
```

But my process substitution  / piping -foo is weak, so of course that isn't quite right.  Surely this is doable, right?